# How to Add Click Listener to Programmatically Added Tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my application i'm programmatically adding a tab like so:

```
'show searchresults tab if not present
If Not TabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tabSearchresults) Then
    TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(3, tabSearchresults)
End If
```

Now I cant seem to manually add a click event listener to that tab in design view, and when I do so in codeview nothing happens when I click that tab.

So the question is,.. How do I add a click listener to that tabSearchresults tab?

Comment: Have a look at the following question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319121/how-to-add-event-handler-to-local-variable-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your `tabSearchresults` is your `TabPage`.
So first create a function which will be handler of `Click` event

```
Private Sub tabSearchresults_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    'your code ...
End Sub
```

Then after line where you initialize your `TabPage` add this handler:

```
tabSearchresults = New TabPage()
AddHandler tabSearchresults.Click, AddressOf tabSearchresults_Click
```